# Track keyboard position on iPad when split and move

Tags: ios, swift, ipad

I am familiar with the method to get keyboard size in response to `keyboardWillShow` and `keyboardWillHide` and accordingly move my app contents.

My problem is on iPad where the user can split and move the keyboard on the screen. There does not seem to be a way to track that. I would like to move my screen contents in response to the position of the moved keyboard.

Comment: There's `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame` and `UIKeyboardDidChangeFrame` notifications for that

Comment: Thanks. But keyboard seems to have a (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0) frame after it is moved.

Comment: `UIKeyboardDidChangeFrame` finally did the truck. thanks @dan you may add this as an accepted answer